# OpenMP pragma is ignored in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, openmp

I have problems getting Visual Studio 2017 to aknowledge 
openMP pragmas like "#pragma omp parallel". I understand that Visual Studio should at least support OpenMP 2.0, but the behavior of my program indicates that my pragmas are alltogether ignored.

In an empty C++ project, I enable the OpenMP setting found under "MyProject>Properties>C/C++>Languages>OpenMP Support", and write the following main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   // I have tried both with and without the following line:
   // omp_set_num_threads(15); 

#pragma omp parallel
    {
        std::cout << "Hello world \n";
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I expect one "Hello world" to be printed from each active thread in the parallel region. Only one line is printed, indicating that I may have missed something.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Interesting.. I could reproduce such behavior.. However, if I tried running such code under older version: VS2015, the issue went away.

Comment: Perhaps the new compiler recognizes that running serialized operations in parallel will slow it down.  I didn't see any change in performance of my benchmarks.

Comment: It works for me as well when using VS2015, so I guess that is a tolerable workaround. Even though it seems strange that VS2017 doesn't handle the pragmas in the same way. 

It makes sense that the compiler may be overriding me because i don't know my own good in this case. However, my code here is just ment to be a reproducable sample. The same issue appears in a parallel for with more complex content.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem right now. Any solutions found?